# Photostream eats my pictures, why?

Tags: iphone, macos, photo-stream

I have the current situation:

in iPhoto, I can see some of my pictures made in the last months ONLY in Photostream. iPhoto says they're imported already, but "show in Library" leads to nowhere.
Since Photostream has a 1000 pictures limit, I'm afraid I'll soon lose some photos I really like.

Last import is supposed to have deleted all pictures from the iPhone, so these pictures are only in Photostream... does anyone have an idea what to do to have these pictures show up in my Events, as they should be?

Comment: Mmm... pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oooookay, now they appeared in a special event with "Photostream" appended...
Only thing that I changed compared to my usual behavior is I connected an iPad Mini in the meantime, which synched said stream...

I have no idea, but they're back, so I'm happy.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you turn on the option "Automatic Import" in your iPhoto preferences :
[image: iPhoto preferences window]

If it is not working, try to disabled and then enabled Photo Stream in iPhoto.